# Trouble pushing code to gitlab repository

Tags: github, gitlab, git-repo

Project owner (michael365) maintain a repository and has provided developer access to me. I am trying to push the code but I am getting this error

```
remote: GitLab: API is not accessible
    To gitlab.com:michael365/bim.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:michael365/bim.git'
```

although I have set the public key in the SSH section, it still it doesn't work. I am issuing the following commands

```
$ git add .

$ git commit -m "Adding Initial Code"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 868 bytes | 868.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: API is not accessible
To gitlab.com:michael365/bim.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:michael365/bim.git'
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Is `origin` even defined?  What does `git remote show origin` show you?  Based on the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html), you should be specifying the full remote ref in your call to `git push --set-upstream`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen on issuing `git remote show origin` I am getting this `* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@gitlab.com:michael365/bim.git
  Push  URL: git@gitlab.com:michael365/bim.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)`

Comment: Is there any other feedback regarding why that pre-receive Git hook failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pre-receive hook declined` indicates that your push was rejected by remote repository after a content check on the changes you are pushing failed.

Ask the admin of remote repo as in what check is rejecting your push. Usually you get a proper error with message stating what check failed.